# How to get Bash to prompt me if I execute a command matching a certain pattern?

Tags: macos, bash

Let's say I were paranoid and wanted extra confirmation prompts on commands that match the following patterns

- `/git push.*master.*/`
- `/rm.*/`
- etc...

Is there any existing tool or way I can configure Bash (on OSX) to re-route me to a `Are you sure? Y/N` prompt whenever I run something matching those patterns?

Comment: Ask on https://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: I don't think this question is OSX specific. However, this question has been asked many times before. http://serverfault.com/questions/337082/how-do-i-prevent-accidental-rm-rf , http://serverfault.com/questions/199798/best-practices-to-prevent-rm-rf-in-bash-scripts , http://superuser.com/questions/367733/how-can-i-block-execution-of-rm-rf-in-a-linux-shell , http://askubuntu.com/questions/217316/how-can-i-prevent-accidental-execution-of-the-rm-r-command , http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86095/preventing-accidental-directory-deletion-making-an-alias-that-contains-options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work. Tested with Bash 3.2.25(1) on RHEL 5.11 and 4.3.42(3) on Cygwin, but it should be OS-independent. It will need to be placed in your `.bash_profile` or some other file that is sourced when `bash` starts. You may want to just put it in its own file and manually `source` it until you're certain it doesn't break anything in your environment.

```
cmd_patterns=(
    'git push.*master.*'
    'rm.*'
)

function xyzzy42
{
    builtin "$@"
}

function confirm_command
{
    local yesno fname
    read -p "Are you sure? (y/n) " yesno
    case "$yesno" in
        y|yes)
            true
        ;;
        *)
            fname="${BASH_COMMAND%% *}"
            eval function $fname \{ echo \"Command aborted.\"\; \}
            PROMPT_COMMAND="xyzzy42 unset -f \"${fname}\""
        ;;
    esac
}

function command_filter
{
    [[ $BASH_COMMAND == xyzzy42* ]] && return
    local p
    for p in "${cmd_patterns[@]}"
    do
        if [[ $BASH_COMMAND =~ $p ]]
        then
            confirm_command
            break
        fi
    done
}

trap -- command_filter DEBUG
```

Here's how it works. The `DEBUG` trap causes the specified command (in this case, `command_filter`) to be run before the commands you run on the CLI. This gives us a chance to insert a confirmation prompt. If the response is `y` or `yes`, nothing special happens and your command is run. Otherwise, we do the following:

1. Create a function with the same name as the command being run; we can't prevent Bash from running *a* command, but we can redefine what that command does. Since Bash looks for functions before external commands, it will run this function instead of the real command.
2. Set `PROMPT_COMMAND` to a command to remove the function we just created. The commands specified by `PROMPT_COMMAND` are run just prior to the command prompt being displayed, but after whatever the previous command was. This cleans up the function we created so it doesn't interfere with future invocations.

Caveats:

- If you already have a `DEBUG` trap, you will need to modify it to run `command_filter` as well. I have no idea what your environment looks like, so this may or may not be trivial.
- Same deal with `PROMPT_COMMAND`.
- Alias expansion occurs before the `DEBUG` trap is triggered. For example, if you have the common `ll` alias for `ls -l`, you would need to filter on `ls -l` (or something else that matches it). The `DEBUG` trap will never see `ll`.
- If you already have a function named for a command you want to filter (e.g. `rm`), it will get overwritten (and then deleted). Rename your function (e.g. `my_rm`), set an alias for it with the name you wanted (`rm`), and filter on your function name.
- The `command_filter` will get run for all interactive commands *and* commands run from `PROMPT_COMMAND`. This is the reason for the `xyzzy42` function; hopefully you don't have a command with anything resembling that name. If you do, rename the function.
- Bash does not anchor regular expressions for you, so something like `rm.*` also matches `xterm` and `usermod`, and `ls` matches `cat /etc/shells`. Be specific with your regular expressions to avoid surprises.
- Bash (unexpectedly) permits non-alphanumeric characters in function names, so you *can* match against something like `^/bin/rm .*`. However, I don't know if it permits precisely the same character set as is permitted for file names, so it may trip up on programs with unusual characters in them.
- Since this method leverages functions to override built-in and external commands, it will **completely fail** in cases where you are running a function from the command-line (and will then proceed to delete the function).

All of that said, this is not much different from aliasing `rm` to `rm -i` in terms of effectiveness. As others have pointed out in the other questions you linked to, it can help protect you, but it's best to just **be careful** when running destructive commands.

Comment: And also there are many ways to bypass the check, e.g., `r\m` or `r'm'` will not be detected. Also `f() { rm "$@"; }; f -rf /` will work without being detected!

Comment: Quite true, but this is not intended to be, nor should it be taken as a security mechanism against hostile input. It's just an extra guard against running an interactive command that could be unintentionally destructive (just as `rm -i` is). Given that most of us probably just blindly click or type "yes" at prompts like these more often then we'd like to admit, the practical utility of both is probably limited anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! Will look into that shortly.